# Removing DNS entries with gcloud

Tags: dns, gcloud

Adding a DNS record with gcloud is all good

```
gcloud dns record-sets transaction start -z my-zone
gcloud dns record-sets transaction add -z my-zone --name "some_domain.com" --ttl 0 --type TXT "test"
gcloud dns record-sets transaction execute -z my-zone
```

But when I try to remove that entry

```
gcloud dns record-sets transaction start -z my-zone
gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove -z my-zone --name "some_domain.com" --ttl 300 --type TXT "test"
gcloud dns record-sets transaction execute -z my-zone
```

I always get this error

> ERROR: (gcloud.dns.record-sets.transaction.remove)  Invalid value for
>   'parameters.name': 'some_domain.com' (code: 400)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [DNS zone file standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) requires complete domain names to end with a trailing '.' character. Since this is a common mistake, other `gcloud dns ...` commands automatically append a trailing '.' to domain names if the user forgets to add one. However, this particular command does not seem to be doing that. This will be fixed soon.

Meanwhile, to workaround it, you need to add a trailing '.' in the domain name. So:

```
gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove -z my-zone --name "some_domain.com." --ttl 300 --type TXT "test"
```

Alternatively, you can use import/export as follows:

```
gcloud dns record-sets export -z my-zone RECORDS-FILE
```

Edit `RECORDS-FILE` to remove the records you do not need. Then:

```
gcloud dns record-sets import -z my-zone --delete-all-existing RECORDS-FILE
```

If you want to clear all records you have created, leaving the `NS` and `SOA` records intact, you can `/dev/null` as import file:

```
gcloud dns record-sets import -z my-zone --delete-all-existing /dev/null
```